# Bumping Azure.Identity 1.7.0 to 1.8.0 leads to Microsoft.Identity.Client error at Azure Function App start

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, nuget, azure-functions-runtime

We have several Azure Functions which reference Azure.Identity. We just bumped all references from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0 (and later 1.8.1). This resulted in one function app being broken - not the others though.

The function app can't even start, the runtime throws the following exception:

> Azure.Identity: The type initializer for 'Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredentialFactory' threw an exception. Azure.Identity: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensibility.AppTokenProviderResult' from assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae'.

I have compared this function (let's call it Function A) to another function (Function B) with identical references.
Function A throws the exception above, Function B works as expected with Azure.Identity 1.8.x.

Here's the .csproj file for Function A:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="6.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Scrutor" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="8.50.0.58025">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- some project references -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Like I said, Function B has the identical references (and some additional ones for Excel stuff, which have nothing to do with this issue). The project references are the same for both, so basically they reference the same projects with reference the same NuGet packages.

The exception states, that Microsoft.Identity.Extensibility.AppTokenProviderResult could not be loaded from Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version 4.21.1.0.
Here's where it gets weird (at least for me).

I have extracted the reference tree of both Function A. This is what I found:

- Microsoft.Identity.Client is referenced twice, once by Azure.Identity in version 4.46.0.0 and once by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in version 4.21.1.0
- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is referenced twice, once by Function A, once by Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, both times in version 2.0.20168.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is referenced once, by Function A, in version 6.0.12.0

```
<Node Id="Azure.Identity, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" Label="Azure.Identity" Category="Assembly" />
<Node Id="Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae" Label="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Category="Assembly" />
<Node Id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" Label="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Category="Assembly" />
<Node Id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=6.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" Label="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Category="Assembly" />
<Node Id="Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae" Label="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Category="Assembly" />
<Link Source="Azure.Identity, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" Target="Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae" Category="Reference" />
<Link Source="FunctionA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Target="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" Category="Reference" />
<Link Source="FunctionA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Target="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=6.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" Category="Reference" />
<Link Source="FunctionA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Target="Azure.Identity, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" Category="Reference" />
<Link Source="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" Target="Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae" Category="Reference" />
<Link Source="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=6.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" Target="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" Category="Reference" />
```

The packages that are referenced by Function A are nowhere to be found in the .csproj file, however Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is referenced in a project reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.12" />
```

So this is what I was able to gather - however, it does not help me in finding out, what the actual issue is. Like I said, Function B has exactly the same references, including the transitive ones, and it just works.
We also checked the infrastructure on Azure's side to make sure both function apps are configured the same, use the same runtime, etc. Everything is identical.

Also noteworthy:
In the beginning, the `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>` in the .csproj was only added to Function B. So, obviously, I thought adding this to Function A would fix it, as the description of that configuration sounds like it could help. It did not help, though.

The next step for me would be trying to reference Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.46.0.0 directly in Function A and see if that helps using the correct assembly.
However, I feel like this would be a workaround and would make maintaining the references harder. Also, why does it work for Function B?

Does anyone have an idea, what could cause this issue? Or how to analyze further?